# How to include a default hmtl markup on a content editor webpart

Tags: 2013, page-layout, branding, design-manager

I have a page layout with one RichHtmlField, this page layout is the one I am using for my blog posts here:

http://levalencia-public.sharepoint.com/Pages/2014/02/Welcome-to-my-sharepoint-online-blog-aspx.aspx

However, every time I create a page I want to include the design of the left box which is always the same.

Please note I am using a page layout with html not aspx (via design manager), and the snippet generated says very clearly to not modify the content inside .

```
<!--CS: Start Page Field: Page Content Snippet-->
            <!--SPM:<%@Register Tagprefix="PageFieldRichHtmlField" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"%>-->
            <!--MS:<PageFieldRichHtmlField:RichHtmlField FieldName="f55c4d88-1f2e-4ad9-aaa8-819af4ee7ee8" runat="server">-->
                <!--PS: Start of READ-ONLY PREVIEW (do not modify)--><div id="ctl02_label" style="display:none">Page Content</div><div id="ctl02__ControlWrapper_RichHtmlField" class="ms-rtestate-field" style="display:inline" aria-labelledby="ctl02_label"><div align="left" class="ms-formfieldcontainer"><div class="ms-formfieldlabelcontainer" nowrap="nowrap"><span class="ms-formfieldlabel" nowrap="nowrap">Page Content</span></div><div class="ms-formfieldvaluecontainer"><div class="ms-rtestate-field">Page Content field value. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div></div></div></div><!--PE: End of READ-ONLY PREVIEW-->
            <!--ME:</PageFieldRichHtmlField:RichHtmlField>-->
            <!--CE: End Page Field: Page Content Snippet-->
```

Comment: You could just reassume control of your project by developing the master page yourself instead of using the Design Manager ;)

Comment: @RJCuthbertson Haha, oh the irony when you find all the new cool toys to not work as well as the old ones ;)

Comment: @RobertLindgren I'm a purist. I take a strong stance in opposition of code auto-generation or WYSIWYG editors... *shudder*

Comment: the tools are to be used if they fit your needs. the tools are to simplify work and in my case it does very well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I where you, I would try to ignore that warning and replace

```
<div class="ms-rtestate-field">Page Content field value. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
```

with

```
<div class="ms-rtestate-field">Whatever you want to add to your Content editor webpart :)</div>
```

I see no reason why this should fail, the worst thing that can happen is that the logic for creating the page layout .aspx from the .html just ignores that you have changed tha value, the best thing that can happen is that it actually works ;)

Comment: trying, brb in 10

Comment: doesnt work, content is ignored :(

Comment: Was afraid of that. Seems there is no way of adding default content in content editor webparts from an HTML page layout then!

Comment: yeah, I assume so.

Comment: I just noticed there is something reusable content library, then on page content this appears on the ribbon, TIME SAVER!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the Snippet gallery, you can put html in the html field. The field is under "Misc" in the Customization section.

This field is a single line of text, so remove any line breaks from your html.